# Why am I getting this ' homePages is not defined no-undef' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm getting the following error, How do I solve this ? I check the 21:16 line there's nothing in it.
How do I solve this ?

```
src\Components\Home-Page\HomePage.js
  Line 21:16:  'homePages' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

**HomePage.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../Header';
import Footer from '../Footer';
import CarouselContainer from '../productCarousel/CarouselContainer.js'
import HomePageProducts from '../homePageProd/HomePageProducts.js';

function HomePage()
{
    return (
    <div>
             <Header></Header>
             <CarouselContainer></CarouselContainer>
       <div>
             <HomePageProducts/>
       </div>
             <Footer></Footer>
   </div>

    );
}

export default HomePage;
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import HomePage from './Components/Homepage/HomePage';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function App() {
  return (
  <HomePage></HomePage>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Everything has been imported correctly. Also there's no such folder called 'Home-Page' it was renamed to 'Homepage'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created HomePage.js file in this path(\Components\Home-Page\HomePage.js) , but import that in App.js with this path(./Components/Homepage/HomePage)